# How to send data using redirect with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I developed an API to show a pop up message when the page loaded.

Not all the pages use the pop up API. For example, if the user go to the `show($id)` page, that doesn't required the pop up api to fire. but in some special cases, I need the pop up to be fired.

Here is my code, ** this code is just to illustrate my point, not an actual working code**

```
public function store(){
    validating the input

    saving them

    $id = get the id

    return Redirect::route('clients.show, $id')
}
```

and in the show function I do this:

```
public function show($id){
   $client =Client::find($id)
   return View::make('clients.profife')->with(array(
   'data' => $client
))
```

#### My question

Is there a way so I can send a data from the `store` function to the `show` function **using Redirect::route** ? and then in the `show` function, I check if this `show` function, I check if this data has been sent of what and then I decide whether to fire the pop up api or not.

}

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In store()

```
return Redirect::route('clients.show, $id')->with( ['data' => $data] );
```

and in `show()` read it with

```
Session::get('data');
```

Comment: Take care that with refresh, the data will disappear because `with` will be pulled one time.

Answer (score 44):

A simple redirect using [helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers).

So you don't need to set `use Redirect` nor `use Session` in your Controller.

After you're done processing something in your Controller, insert:

```
return redirect()->route('clients.show')->with([ 'id' => $id ]);
```

To retrieve the variable `'id'` in route `'clients.show'`, use:

```
// in PHP
$id = session()->get('id');

// in Blade
{{ session()->get('id') }}
```

Comment: This works fine, and looks a little neater to my eyes.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Sorry, I've improved my explanation. and thanks

Comment: I was giving you a compliment and gave you a +1 :)

Comment: or just `session('id');` (laravel 5.7)

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

After sending the information via the following code in Laravel 8:

```
return redirect()->route( 'clients.show' )->with( [ 'id' => $id ] );
```

I will receive the amount sent with $id

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can define path in route like below:

```
Route::get('store/{id?}/{param1?}/{param2?}/{param3?}', 'clients@store');
```

You can pass multiple parameter in function and read in controller by passing argument..

You can define in controller :

```
public function store(id, param1,param2,param3){
//read the param values
}
```