# How to send data to the view using redirect with Laravel without using Session?

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5.5

I want to send data from the controller to my view without using session to get the data in the view.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078452/how-to-send-data-using-redirect-with-laravel), they suggested to use `return redirect('home')->with(['data' => $value]);` but I have to use `Session::get('data')` in my view.

I know that it can be solved by using return `view('myView')->with('data', 'value')` but I want the URL to be changed to *www.myurl.com/home* when navigating to the home page and I cannot perform this with `view('myView')->with('data', 'value')`.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no other way, you really need to use `Session::get`. However, we can do a workaround it, but it's messy.

```
// some controller function
return redirect('home')->with(['data' => $value]);
```

Now in your `home` controller function, do this:

```
SomeController@home
...
$data = [];

// if you need to pass other data to view, put it in data[]
// e.g., $data['username'] = Auth::user()->username;

if (Session::has('data')) {
    $data['data'] = Session::get('data');
}

return view('myView', compact($data));
```

There, in your view you can just check if `data` is set.

```
<!-- myView.blade.php -->
<span>{{ isset($data) ? $data : '' }}</span>
```

For me, it's merely the same as accessing the `Session` from the view, because if you did, this is what your view will look like.

```
<!-- myView.blade.php -->
<span>{{ Session::has('data') ? Session::get('data') : '' }}</span>
```

You can also use `session()` global helper instead of the `Session` facade.