# How to pass data when redirecting to another page?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass user data when redirecting to another page with that data and use it in that page.

```
$mobile = (int) $request->mobile;

        $user = User::where('mobile',$mobile)->first();
        if ($user->count() > 0 && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password))
        {
            return redirect('/user_info')->with('user',$user);
        }
```

The view that i want to use the user data in :

```
  <div class="row">
        <h3>Valnteer: {{ $user->name }}</h3>
    </div>
```

The problem I get is :

> Undefined variable: user

Comment: You can set session variable?

Comment: This is the solution of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078452/how-to-send-data-using-redirect-with-laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send data using redirect with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078452/how-to-send-data-using-redirect-with-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store your data in the [session](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session).

In order to pass data just once, there's a concept called [flashing](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#flash-data) for you.