# How to run Artisan command without a console

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Someone know how to start command without console

Let me explain
After the file is downloaded successfully, you need to run the command **php artisan db:seed**
I tried this option but I got an error as a result
Maybe someone knows another solution to this problem
I will be very grateful
I tried this option but I got an error as a result

```
$file = file($request->file->getRealPath());
$fileName = resource_path('upload/csv/accounts/' . date('y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.csv');
$path = file_put_contents($fileName, $file);
return redirect()->route('admin.accounts');
```

I tried this option

```
$file = file($request->file->getRealPath());
$fileName = resource_path('upload/csv/accounts/' . date('y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.csv');
$path = file_put_contents($fileName, $file);
return redirect()->route('admin.accounts');
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

And this

```
$file = file($request->file->getRealPath());
$fileName = resource_path('upload/csv/accounts/' . date('y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.csv');
$path = file_put_contents($fileName, $file);
return redirect()->route('admin.accounts')->with(Artisan::call('db:seed'));
```

Comment: Please check this - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#terminable-middleware

Comment: `I got an error as a result` - what error? In your first example, the `Artisan` command will never run, because you already `return`ed.  Why not simply switch those 2 lines around?

Answer (score 0):

I think this option might work. but put artisan call above return. any lines of code after return will be ignored.

```
$file = file($request->file->getRealPath());
$fileName = resource_path('upload/csv/accounts/' . date('y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.csv');
$path = file_put_contents($fileName, $file);
Artisan::call('db:seed');// <---- this line 
return redirect()->route('admin.accounts');
```

Comment: Maybe I incorrectly described the problem
I need the console command to run only after the redirect
Otherwise, the file download will continue in parallel with the console command, and if it takes a long time, cloudflare will kill this process.

Comment: first, send data with redirect like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078452/how-to-send-data-using-redirect-with-laravel
then in controller check if data is exist. if data exist then run artisan command. but I think this is not safe.