# Undefined variable in blade after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4.

I have form in my project. User can submit the form and I can generate report on values the user provided with. Initial issue was that the form was resubmitting on page refresh that was undesirable. I tried to prevent it with **redirect->** but the  issue is I'm unable to fetch the variable from controller into my view.

This is error on my blade.

```
Undefined variable: seller
```

Controller

```
 $seller = Sellers::take(1)->latest()->get();
 return redirect()->route('private_seller_report')->with(['seller' => $seller]);
```

Blade

```
@php
  $seller = Session::get('seller');
@endphp

    @foreach($seller as $row)
      <a href="#">{{$row->seller_name}}</a>
    @endforeach
```

So my ultimate goal is to prevent the form submission on refresh.

Comment: Make sure that. the name route `private_seller_report` use the right page, where you try to catch the `$seller` variable

Comment: @sta It's 110% correct and intended page where I want to get the variable.

Comment: If you use `return redirect()->route('private_seller_report')->with(['seller' => $seller]);` . You need to use `Session::get('seller');`in blade. This way you can get the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078452/how-to-send-data-using-redirect-with-laravel ,please see this link

Comment: I think its on your session, like `@foreach(session()->get('seller')  as $row)`

Comment: Which page extend the `private_seller_report` route? You can pass it to view instead of route, like `return view('view_name')->with(['seller' => $seller]);`

Comment: Please share more details. Which line shows that error?

Comment: @xNoJustice
See mu updated blade above.
Now it's throwing another erro.
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @Nico Haase, the error is pretty clear here, for a laravel developer.

Comment: @sta
Please check my updated blade.
It's throwing another error
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"..........Even I gave it a try with your code((session()->get('seller') as $row)) but still the same error.

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya
Thanks for your suggestion. 
But now I' m getting another error that's 
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Btw, your model is `Sellers` or `Seller`,  please make a dd on controller `dd($seller);` and see the output, to be sure `$seller` is not empty

Comment: <?php
if (Session::has('seller')) {
    $selected_services_data = Session::get('seller');
    if (!empty($seller)) {
        ?>
                    @foreach($seller as $row)
                    
                      @endforeach                                                    
        <?php
    }
}
?>

Comment: @Shaan see my answer.Hope fully it will help to you easily.perfectly works in my project

Comment: Whats the output of `dd($seller);` in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it. The `->with()` method is not intended for this use, but you can just pass data in the route method instead, like so:

```
Route::get('/first-route', static function() {
    return redirect()->route('second-route', ['data' => [1, 2, 3]]);
});

Route::get('/second-route', static function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return view('test-view', ['data' => $request->input('data')]);
})->name('second-route');
```

Keep in mind that you are redirecting to another route, so you need the route you redirected to, to pass the data into the view. In this example, you can see that I pass `[1, 2, 3]` into `second-route` and then get the data via the request object. Then I pass that into the view in the `second-route`.

If I do a `dd($request->input('data');` in `second-route`, I will get:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]
```

So my best guess is that you never pass the data into the view, after the first route redirects to the next.

**UPDATE:**
Take a second and read the documentation about the `->with()` method https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data and look at the PHPDoc of the code in `RedirectResponse.php`: `Flash a piece of data to the session.`

You can see here what the "flash" is used for: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-implement-flash-messages-with-exampleexample.html

Comment: I appreciate your approach but only the issue is the data I want to send is table from database. I don't think so that I can pass table values as data from route.

Comment: You can pass any data you want between routes and views. It doesn't matter that its a hydrated model from the database. It works just fine. I did the example with `[1, 2, 3]` to keep it simple, but you could do `['data' => Sellers::take(1)->latest()->get()]` and that would work just fine.

A route redirect does not take you to a view, but another method in a controller, so the `Undefined variable: seller` error from the blade file tells me that it was not passed into the view. 

I hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

first time you need to call sellerPage method using this route.

```
Route::get('/seller/page','SellerController@sellerPage')->name('private_seller_report');

  public function sellerPage()
  {
    $seller = Sellers::take(1)->latest()->get()->toArray();
    return view('your.blade')->with(['seller' => $seller]);
  }
```

Comment: You didn't follow my question. 
I know this syntax. But If I do like that my form will again submit on refresh that's what I don't wanted to see.

Comment: can you see it as first time loading?

Comment: Yes I can see that.

Comment: @Shaan. try this second solution

Comment: why are you using Session for that. you don't need it

Comment: Look, after form submit, the page I' m trying to access is "private_seller_report" with variable named "seller". 
What you are saying is out of box for me.

Comment: You are using the function for something it is not intended for. It is not meant to use for passing data. Again, check the update to my answer and test it before rejecting it as a solution.

Comment: you can call the 'private_seller_report'  route after form submission.  your code, you are trying to return ROUTE with DATA. not a VIEW (because lost your data in the second time). but I'm trying to return a VIEW with DATA. not a ROUTE ( once try this ).

Comment: your seller data wouldn't be lost after you refresh your page. because you already load that page with seller DATA. because I return only VIEW, not ROUTE

Comment: like my code, you are refreshing URL-  /seller/page every time. when call /seller/page. your page will load with [Seller Data ]